# Htaccess application/type with PHP as FastCGI

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, fastcgi

Is there a way to use .htaccess with PHP as CGI/FastCGI?

I would like to be able to have other extensions open as PHP.

I have tried the following:

```
AddType application/fcgid-script .phpd
AddHandler fcgid-script .phpd
```

EDIT:
With PHP as FastCGI does this mean I need to do something else other then .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use these:

```
AddHandler php-fastcgi .php .php5
AddType text/html .php .php5
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php5
```

Note, PHP will not process files if PHP content doesnt start with `<?php` and will process files  with `<?` only if allowed by php.ini

and if you want to be able to use it with htaccess - you'll need to `allowoverride` it.

Comment: Where do I add allowoverride?

Comment: In apache configuration, directory section: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride